# Mix SATA and IDE drives for dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows Vista on a 180G IDE HD. I have Ubuntu 12.04 on a 320G SATA HD. I want to put them in the same box and dual boot. How can I do this without goofing up?
The motherboard Acer M1100 has one IDE and the rest SATA. It has a legal install. That is the motherboard I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though if you still have an IDE drive it must be a good 6+ years old now so you probably should replace it.